# PeerJs close video call not firing close event

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to create a one-directional video app with PeerJs. I've succesfully been able to run my own peer server and connect on a button click, but I'm unable to close the connection so that the peers can receive/establish a new connection with a new peer.

Every user will either be a host or a client, it will never be backwards. So the host can choose which client to connect to and the client will start to stream its camera feed back to the host. The `closeCon()` function is called with a button click.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      peer = new Peer('100001', {host: 'my.url', port: '9900', path: '/peerjs', key: 'peerjs', secure: true, debug: 3});
      peer.on("open", function(id) {
          console.log("My peer ID is: " + id);
      });
        video = document.getElementById('vidSrc');
    })


    function callTheGuy(id){
      var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
      getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function(stream) {
        window.call = peer.call(id, stream);
        localStream = stream;
        window.call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
          let video = document.getElementById('vidArea');
          video.srcObject = remoteStream;
          video.play();
          $("#videoModal").modal('show')
        });
      }, function(err) {
        console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
      });
      }

      function closeCon(){
        window.call.close();
      }
```

This all works great, i get my video feed, no problem. Here is my client code:

```
peer = new Peer(serverId, {
    host: "my.url",
    port: "9900",
    path: "/peerjs",
    key: "peerjs",
    debug: 3,
    secure: true
});

peer.on("open", function(id) {
    console.log("My peer ID is: " + id);
});

var getUserMedia =
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
peer.on("call", function(call) {
    getUserMedia(
        { video: true, audio: false },
        function(stream) {
            localStream = stream;
            call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log("Failed to get local stream", err);
        }
    );
    call.on("close", function() {
        console.log("closing");
    });
});
```

The issue is that when I call `closeCon()`, the client file is not receiving the close event. The part of

```
call.on("close", function() {
        console.log("closing");
    });
```

never gets fired. I'm not really sure why this is happening but unless that close event gets processed, the client stays connected to the original host and can't accept connections from subsequent host requests. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on 7 Mar 2021

I found that is an issue, PeerJs hasn't fixed yet. (Issue link: https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/636)

You can trigger the close event in Socketio "disconnect" for a workaround solution

Server

```
socket.on("disconnect", (reason)=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit("user-disconnected", userId); 
    });
```

Client

```
socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId)=>{
        // remove video or add your code here
   });
```

Comment: but did we need a dedicated server? or we can just use peerjs cloud server?

Comment: need a nodejs server @naoval

Comment: this isn't a great work around, as soon as you involve a server for handling stuff like this, it's no longer P2P

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the issue after discovering my peerConnections continued to send stream data using chrome://webrtc-internals. I am currently using the public peerjs server. The [MediaConnection](https://peerjs.com/docs.html#mediaconnection) does not fire the `close` event, but the [DataConnection](https://peerjs.com/docs.html#dataconnection) still class does. My particular flow waits for the remote to initiate a (data)connection and then starts a call.

I was able too close the MediaConnection by:

1. opening both a DataConnection and a MediaConnection to a remote peer
2. monitoring the MediaConnection close event
3. Closing all WebRTC[peerConnections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) after as part of the DataConnection close handler

This looks like:

```
function handlePeerDisconnect() {
  // manually close the peer connections
  for (let conns in peer.connections) {
    peer.connections[conns].forEach((conn, index, array) => {
      console.log(`closing ${conn.connectionId} peerConnection (${index + 1}/${array.length})`, conn.peerConnection);
      conn.peerConnection.close();

      // close it using peerjs methods
      if (conn.close)
        conn.close();
    });
  }
}

peer.on('connection', conn => {
    let call = peer.call(peerToCall, localStream);
   
    // peerjs bug prevents this from firing: https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/636
    call.on('close', () => {
        console.log("call close event");
        handlePeerDisconnect();
    });
}

    // this one works
    conn.on('close', () => {
        console.log("conn close event");
        handlePeerDisconnect();
    });
});
```

Comment: Browsed a lot but end up here , Thanks this worked !

Answer (score 0):

No, it fires the close event. but you first do as follows:

1. server

   ```
     socket.on('disconnect', () =>{
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId);
        })
   ```
2. client

```
    const peers = {};
        function connectToNewUser (userId, stream){
        ...

        call.on('close', () =>{
            video.remove();
        })

      
        
        peers[userId] = call;

    }
```

and then in client emit the event:

```
socket.on('user-disconnected', userId =>{
        console.log(userId);
        if (peers[userId]){
            peers[userId].close();
        }
        
    })
```

Comment: Please don't use code snippets if they aren't intended to run. Edit and change to regular code blocks.